# Networking crashes, no restart possible without reboot

Tags: networking, wifi, motion

I'm running stretch on a pi3 with motion. I can browse this no problem from a pc for as long as I've cared to try but when I try to access it through firefox on my android phone, bang networking goes down. No motion, no ssh, but through a local login it seems fine, except there's no access to the network.

Wlan0 still has the same ip, but none of the following work to restart networking;

```
sudo service networking restart
sudo ifdown wlan0, sudo ifup wlan0
sudo systemctl restart networking.
```

Everything comes back as expected after a reboot.

Can't find anything in the logs, just using the internal wifi. This is always repeatable.

Only thing I can find is

```
brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_hostmail: unknown mailbox data content: 0x40012" in journalctl -b
```

Thanks!

Comment: `I can browse this no problem from a pc` ... how is the PC connected?

Comment: What OS are you using? Are you **ACTUALLY** running `Debian` networking?

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem is related to this https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1342

> **WARNING** "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911
>   Even the [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) documentation now warns "Even on Raspbian you should only use this with a good reason. This gets you the latest bleeding edge kernel/firmware."

Fixed it by "sudo rpi-update" and a reboot.